# ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. null - Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, match, case, hortonworks-data-platform

I have written a pig code where i want to match a column with multiple strings. Eg.

```
    A = FOREACH A1 GENERATE
    c1, c2, c3,

--i have substituted junk values--

case
when (  (
       column_name matches '.*abc.*'
    OR column_name matches '.*sdf.*'
    OR column_name matches '.*bcd.*'
    OR column_name MATCHES '.*def.*'
    OR column_name MATCHES '.*efg.*'
    OR column_name MATCHES '.*ggg.*'
    OR column_name MATCHES '.*ghi.*'
    OR column_name MATCHES '.*hij.*'
    OR column_name MATCHES '.*ijk.*'
    OR column_name MATCHES '.*jkl.*'
    OR column_name MATCHES '.*klm.*'
    OR column_name MATCHES '.*lmn.*'
    or column_name matches '.*mno.*'
    or column_name matches '.*mnb.*'
    or column_name matches '.*opq.*'
    or column_name matches '.*pqr.*'
    or column_name matches '.*qrs.*'
    or column_name matches '.*stuv.*'
    or column_name matches '.*tuvw.*'
    or column_name matches '.*wxy.*'
    or column_name matches '.*tuvwx.*'
    or column_name matches '.*xyz.*'
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    ) then 1
            else 0 as c4;
```

It is observed that when the number of **OR column_name MATCHES '---'** statements go beyond 672, the pig script fails to run with the error:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. null

java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.zip.Deflater.ensureOpen(Deflater.java:543)
        at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:426)
        at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:352)
        at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:251)
        at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.write(ObjectOutputStream.java:1840)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1533)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

**Kindly suggest a solution or an alternative to cater this requirement.**

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing a custom filter function [1](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/udf.html#filter-functions) where you are more in control over RAM consumption. It's quite possible that you don't need RegEx but rather a substring search.

Comment: UPD: you generate, not filter, so it should be an eval function https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/udf.html#eval-functions

Comment: So, basically I need to write a UDF and search the column value (substring) in the required set of values like ('abc | def | ghi | jkl | mno').
Is this the correct understanding @patrungel?

Comment: Correct for writing a UDF,  but it's not for searching for column value in your list; at least I got the impression that you search for patterns _in_ values.

Comment: Thanks...I will try writing a UDF and update on the status.

I just wanted to know if this is a limitation to the CASE WHEN---MATCHES--- condition that i cannot exceed 672 such statements ?

Comment: I have also read an approach where i have to divide the OR conditions into different relations and then use UNION later to sum up the result. But this will lead to additional processing and I don't feel this is a suitable approach.

Comment: Re limitation: you hit stack overflow error (ironically), so this is not something imposed by Apache Pig authors.

Comment: StackOverflow Error :P

The reason I am asking this is because, in future if I have to change something in my clauses, I will have to change the UDF and recompile the jar...follow the entire process. I think UDF should be the last option in Pig.

Comment: Make the UDF accept clauses as initialization parameters and then use DEFINE to pass those. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/basic.html#define-udfs 
Another option is to write the UDF in Python, it introduces less deployment costs.